# Is this Enough to Secure againts SQL Injections?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, sql-injection

I'm trying to secure a older classic asp web site (that has about 1,000 (.asp) pages) using MS SQL 2008 R2 (Express Edition).

I found a code (see below) on how to Parameterized Queries and the code looks to be the easiest for me to understand and use on all of the pages that need to be changed.

If I was to convert all of the ms sql queries (that will look something like the code below) will that be enough to protect against an ms sql injection attack ? or is there more that I will need to add/change ?

```
    set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")  
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?"
    ...  
    cmd1.Parameters(0) = Request.Form("login")
    cmd1.Parameters(1) = Request.Form("password")
    ...
```

Comment: It should do as far as SQL injection is concerned.  I'm still a fan of stored procedures and named parameters.  SPs provide a clearly defined interface and, as DB objects, can have security applied.  Explicitly defining the parameters and their data types helps to pin down the interface.  Default values for parameters can be provided and validation done within the SP.

Comment: @HABO will the code that kd7 provided (see answer# 2 below) slove all of the problems or are there still holes that can lead to a problem? (I'm sorry I know it's probably a noob question but I just want to understand what I have to do to make this a secure web app. and to start chaning the 1,000+ pages) Thanks alot...

Comment: It will work for a simple website, but becomes a maintenance headache in larger environments.  Part of the problem is having little snippets of SQL scattered all over.  What should be a minor database change and updated SPs becomes a hunt through all of the places that contain SQL, or build it on the fly.  The execution plan for an SP is kept and reused on each call (unless you specify `WITH RECOMPILE`).  That usually helps performance.  An SP can provide limited access to data that the caller could not otherwise access, important in larger projects with multiple applications.

Comment: @HABO Thank you so much for the input, can you please direct me to a tutorial or something that you approve for me (a noob in all of this) to read, some material that I can understand ? Thank you so much for everything HABO.

Comment: You're [here](http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2008/6/26/Are-stored-Procedures-any-more-secure-than-parameterized-queries).  Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199886/stored-procedures-vs-no-stored-procedures-security-viewpoint) and [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html).  [Advanced SQL security topics.](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html)  [Alternate viewpoint.](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/05/25/why-i-do-not-use-stored-procedures/)  The issue of maintenance is a matter of experience and your environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its been a while since I've seen the old Adodb command syntax, but I think you would want something like:

```
set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
strSql = "Select * From users where username=@username and password=@password"
objCommand.Parameters.Append.CreateParameter
         ("@username", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Request.Form("login"))
objCommand.Parameters.Append.CreateParameter
         ("@password", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Request.Form("password"))
```

As always, don't create dynamic sql statements without a type safe parameter encoding, I think even old school ADO provides this via CreateParameter.

Comment: Thanks so much for the above example it is really helping me out better understand how to do this. I'm a total noob in this but I want to understand how it works so I make sure that I'm doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code you provided in your question is secured against Sql Injections.

However, [as noted in this article on mitigating Sql Injection](http://blogs.technet.com/b/neilcar/archive/2008/05/23/sql-injection-mitigation-using-parameterized-queries-part-2-types-and-recordsets.aspx), your code will have "a minor performance issue because ADODB is going to have to made a round-trip to SQL to figure out the parameter type before it can execute the query."

You can resolve this by explicitly specifying the parameter type in your code using [`CreateParameter`](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp)